# Probability that two numbers do not follow each other and are distributed over a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, uniform-distribution

Assume a sequence $S$ of numbers out of the set $N={1..n}$.

Example:
$$S = "123312"$$

Set of all pairs would be:
$$M = (2,3),(3,3), (3,1)$$

Not in $M$:

$(1,1)$ : not occuring in the sequence next to each other.

$(1,2)$ : occuring twice

Numbers are order-dependent. $(1,2)$ != $(2,1)$

What is the probability that all pairs $(a$,$b)$ out of the set $M$ that occur **only once** in $S$  are evenly distributed over the length of the sequence $S$? How do i model "evenly distributed" over $S$ best?

(In reality i would like an even distance between the pairs $(a$,$b)$. Or at least the probability for that.) 
Should i model it as part of Quintiles with bins in which the pairs fall(like i highlighted in this example? What would be the mathematical term for such a distribution?

[image: example]

The arrow represents the sequence $S$ made up of instances of $N$ of length $L$. The yellow circles denote the position $p$ of a pair $(a$,$b)$ that only once occurs in $S$. 
The horizontal arrow denotes the distance $D$ between two yellow circles.

I also would like to plug into this different probabilities from the set N={1..n} with pN=p(1..n).

What i have tried so far is computing the probability that a pair occurs in a certain part of the sequence and not in the other parts. I them sum this up over all possible pairs. However the equations get pretty nasty somehow and mathematica cannot simplify them by much. Pretty sure, that there should be a solution that is not too complicated.

Comment: a/b is a pair. not a fraction. how can i express that more clearly?

Comment: Say $(a,b)$ if it is the pair you consider. I guess it should be a pair out of $N^2$, not $N$, then. $S$ is a set of pairs, right?

Comment: The fractions in your drawing should be pairs also?

Comment: yes you are right. the fractions in the drawing are pairs also.

Comment: Have you listed all possible pairs of $M$ in your example? What about $(1,2)$ and $(1,1)$?

Comment: $(1,2)$ is not unique, (1,1) are not next to each other. added into the question

Comment: @tarrasch : Do you distinguish (a,b) from (b,a) in your pairs or not?

Comment: yes those are two pairs.

Comment: @tarrasch I think it is called [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#cite_note-1) (or Maximum length sequence, M-sequece), the number of such sequences have been calculated by some mathimaticians.

Comment: the De Bruijn sequence is used for creating a sequence that consists of these pairs. what i would like is to analyse the distribution of those numberpairs

Comment: @tarrasch Isn't the probability equals to (the number of all possible De Bruijin sequences)/(the number of all sequences)? One slightly change should be made because De Bruijin sequence is cyclic.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood, that should be the lower bound

Comment: yes, that would be the lower bound. a brujin sequence is the most condensed form where you get all pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I will only consider the question, 'How do i model "evenly distributed" over $S$ best?' and even for that question I will just give you a search term. If you have a finite collection of numbers $$\{{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}}$$ with $0\le x_i\lt1$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, then you can calculate a quantity called the *discrepancy* of the set, which will give you a measure of how far it is from being evenly distributed. So my advice is that you hunt around for discussions of the mathematical concept of discrepancy.